# Как получить заголовок окна приемника с помощью winapi C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

Как по дескриптору(т.е. номеру) окна вывести его заголовок,у меня не получается может кто-нибудь подскажет?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace parol_udal
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto,SetLastError=true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string sClassName,string sWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto,SetLastError=true)]
         public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto ,SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GetWindowText (IntPtr hwnd,StringBuilder lpString,int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        static void Main()
        {
           IntPtr thisWindow = FindWindow(null, "Окно");
           IntPtr Rod = thisWindow;

           IntPtr otherWindow = FindWindowEx(Rod, IntPtr.Zero, "RICHEDIT50W", null);

            int len = GetWindowTextLength(otherWindow);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
            len = GetWindowText(otherWindow, sb, len);

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString(0,len)); //выводит пустую строку
            Console.WriteLine(thisWindow); //выводлит дескриптор родителя
            Console.WriteLine(otherWindow);//выводит дескриптор приемника
            Console.ReadKey(true); 
       }
    }
}
Please help, how to get title "otherWindow"?
```

Comment: надо len = len * 2; и в GetWindowText вместо len передать sb.Capacity -- пример на c# [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460301/482127#482127)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Согласно MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx):

> To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a WM_GETTEXT message directly instead of calling GetWindowText.

Если вы пытаетесь получить текст контрола в другом процессе (а имя RICHEDIT50W предполагает, что это так), нужно посылать WM_GETTEXT напрямую.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, [Out] StringBuilder lParam);
```

...

```
const int WM_GETTEXT = 0xD;
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(65535);
SendMessage(hWnd_of_Notepad_Editor, WM_GETTEXT, buffer.Length, buffer);
```